# Comparing ideals in posets

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, applied-mathematics

Consider a partially ordered set $P$, and two upper sets $U_1$, $U_2$ in this poset.

What are some natural ways to measure how equal these two upper sets are?
This question arise naturally in the study of proteins which upper closed sets.

Of course, all measures on sub-graph similarity in graphs can be applied here,
but perhaps using that these are upper-closed sets in a poset, make some constructions more natural.

What similarity means, is of course depending on the similarity measuring function,
but say $sim(U_1,U_1)$ should be big, and $sim(U_1,U_2)$ is small if $U_1$ and $U_2$ if the overlap between $U_1$ and $U_2$ is small.

Comment: Can you say more about what you really want here? For instance, the ratio of the cardinality of the intersection to that of the union seems to satisfy everything you want.

Comment: Sure, but that does not really take into consideration that it is a poset. Say we have a unique top. Then all upper closed sets contain the top, so in some sense, it should not really be taken into consideration..

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure of exactly what you are looking for, so I will post something that sounds reasonable. If $P$ is a poset, then the collection of all lower sets (and upper sets as well) forms a frame. Furthermore, every frame is a Heyting algebra, so every frame has an $\rightarrow$ operation. In a Heyting algebra, one may define an "if and only if" operation by letting $x\leftrightarrow y=(x\rightarrow y)\wedge(y\rightarrow x)$.

If $P$ is a poset, then let $L$ denote the frame of all lower sets. Then $A\rightarrow B$ is the largest lower set with $(A\rightarrow B)\cap A\subseteq B$. In particular, $x\in A\rightarrow B$ if and only if $\downarrow x\cap A\subseteq B$. Thus, $x\in A\leftrightarrow B$ if and only if $\downarrow x\cap A=\downarrow x\cap B$.